# Select all rows from pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, slim

I'm having a bit of trouble selecting pivot table rows with Eloquent on Slim Framework. I have the following relations:

**tb_bet** (id, ...)
**tb_fixture** (id, ...)
**tb_bet_fixture** (bet_id, fixture_id, status)

**Models**:

Bet.php:

```
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Bet extends Model {

    protected $connection = 'client';
    protected $table = 'tb_bet';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function fixtures() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Fixture')->withPivot('status');
    }
}
```

Fixture.php:

```
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Fixture extends Model {

        protected $connection = 'client';
        protected $table = 'tb_fixture';
        public $timestamps = false;

        public function bets() {
            return $this->belongsToMany('Bet')->withPivot('status');
        }
    }
```

I'm able to query all bets from a fixture and all fixtures from a bet but what I really need is to do this: `select * from tb_bet_fixture where bet_id = 1`. So I have a list of all fixture status for a given bet. Kinda like this:

```
bet:{
  'id': 1,
  'pivot': [
      {bet_id: 1, fixture_id: 2, status: true},
      {bet_id: 1, fixture_id: 3, status: false},
      {bet_id: 1, fixture_id: 4, status: true}
  ]
}
```

I thought of use raw query but whenever I try to declare `use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;` on my controller and use `$users = DB::select('select * from tb_users');` as a test I get a `Database [default] not configured.` error and I can't figure how to access the '$capsule' variable which contains the current connection(yes, I use multiple connections to different db's) and is defined on a Middleware. Anyway, I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: Create a model

If i were to use a pivot as a model . I would create a Model for pivot table. So that you can directly query the table. Like this.

```
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Bet;

class BetFixture extends Model 
{
    protected $table =‘tb_bet_fixture’;

    public function bets() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Bet::class);
    }
}
```

This would make it easier and clearer than querying through as u are selecting from a pivot directly like this

```
select * from tb_bet_fixture where bet_id = 1.
```

Option 2: Select using fixture, with specific bet

If you want to select fixture with a specific bet through fixtures you can query like this.

```
Fixture::with(‘bets’ => function($query) use ($betId) {
    $query->where(‘tb_bet_fixture.bet_id,$betId);
});
```

Comment: I just saw the answer but the model approach is the one that solved my problem yesterday. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Creating a model for the pivot table was exactly what I needed to hear.  Thank you!